# How do I estimate a prediction interval from a weighted sample?

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I have a vector of data with their standard errors:

```
Estimate <- c(0.254719513441046, 0.130492717014416, 0.0386710035855823, 0.14118562325405, 0.160649388742147, 0.60363287936294, 0.173485345603584, 0.425817607348994, 0.128802795868366, 0.104136474748465)
SE <- c(0.126815201703205, 0.240179692822184, 0.248612907189712, 0.379800224602374, 0.0799874163236805, 0.170568135051654, 0.108163615496468, 0.0585237357996271, 0.16702614577514, 0.124308993809982)
```

I need to form a prediction interval for new elements that will be drawn from the same parent population. At first I thought I would do a linear regression to estimate the mean and the error on the mean:

```
summary(lm(Estimate ~ 1, weights = 1/SE^2))
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.28014    0.04996   5.607 0.000331 ***
```

But when I try naively to call `predict()` here is what I get:

```
predict(lm(Estimate ~ 1, weights = 1/SE^2), newdata = data.frame(x = 0), interval = "prediction")
        fit       lwr      upr
1 0.2801405 -2.860802 3.421083
Warning message:
In predict.lm(lm(Estimate ~ 1, weights = 1/SE^2), newdata = data.frame(x = 0),  :
  Assuming constant prediction variance even though model fit is weighted
```

Did I do this right? Is the 95% confidence interval really [-2.86 3.42]? Do I need to worry about the warning?